# Identifying unused JNDI keys

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, jndi, weblogic11g

I have tens of JNDI key-value pairs on my application server (Glassfish & Weblogic with mirrored evnironments i.e same keys, same jndi sources etc).

Some of these key-value pairs are unused. I'm wondering if it's possible to find the JNDI keys that haven't been accessed in a while.

Obviously, the other option is to manually go through each key one by one and see if any of the applications are using it. But wondering if there's an easier way to do this.